# Hook into before unload of salesforce standard tab in lighting web component

Tags: lwc-dom, lightning-web-components

Is there any way to detect and execute some JavaScript method before unload of salesforce standard tab inside LWC.

Comment: Hi, Sanjay Wellcome to the community. Could you please elaborate more on your question with some example. What kind of tab it is and the LWC is associated with that.

Comment: Hi Avijit, Thanks for the quick response. Problem Statement :  I have few standard tab(like Account, Agreement, custom tab(custom object)). Inside custom tab after click on a record, opens record detail page, which is built on custom lwc component. If I have to do any modification on those lwc components, without saving it moving to different standard tab then want to throw warning message saying, “you have unsaved data please take action”. And based on user action I can retain the same page or moved to different tab.

Comment: Unfortunately, we do not have this capability but we do have a dirty attribute in a console app. lightning:inputField doesn’t provide a way to indicate that a field has been modified but not saved.

lightning-input-field supports a dirty attribute to indicate that the field has been modified by the user but not saved or submitted.
For more information, see the recordEditForm differences.

Comment: Thanks a lot Avijit for analyzing my issue. So currently i am using a data table grid inside my lwc component and dynamically i am adding row inside the grid. Each row's data i am fetching from multiple object combining and appending to grid. As its a lwc data table we cann't use lightning:inputfield